"Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'." when trying to build for android
Suddenly getting this issue, only for android builds. This shows up:
Launching lib\main.dart on 24069PC21G in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
ERROR:C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\audio_session\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR:C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\just_audio\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :just_audio) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\just_audio\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :audio_session) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\audio_session\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Gits\rhythmic\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

These are my dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  provider: ^6.1.2
  just_audio: ^0.9.41
  http: ^1.2.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  theme_mode_handler: ^3.0.0

This happens for both real and emulated devices. Desktop (windows) and web work just fine. I really don't know what to do anymore ^^'
Things I tried:

changing target java version in android\app\build.gradle to various LTS versions (1.8/8, 11, 17, 21)
using a more recent wrapper (8.4 from 7.5)
creating a new project
clearing gradle and android studio cache, clearing build folder
Enabling multidex in android\app\build.gradle

